# How To Use A Windows Environment Variable Independent Of Shell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a need within a `.bat` file to change to a certain directory which is referenced by an environment variable.  Something along these lines:

```
cd %TMP%
```

And this works fine from Windows CMD shell.  However if I try to run the bat within a Powershell terminal window, it appears that the command simply doesn't work. This does though:

```
cd $Env:TMP
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to keep things to one `.bat` file but still allow users to run it under both the *CMD* prompt and the *PS* prompt.  I can think of some hacky ways to check to see if I'm under *CMD* (as opposed to *PS*) but I'd like to know if there's a better solution.

One thing I noticed is that the `PROMPT` environment variable is present with *CMD* but not with *Powershell* but, as I say, that seems a bit hacky and potentially error-prone.

I'm not trying to pad my rep so if this has already been asked and answered, please point me to it.  I just want to find something less hacky than trying to figure out which shell the `bat` is being run in and changing the `cd` command to suit it.

By the way, since it may make a difference, I'm running under *Powershell 4*. I could probably use a .cmd file if that would make any difference but I'd be surprised if it did.

---

**EDIT:**

I guess maybe I wasn't as clear as I could be. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to get the value of an environment variable that will work within a .bat file that will work regardless of whether or not the .bat file is run under the cmd shell or the powershell shell.

Comment: Why the downvote? Seriously what's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running batch files from PowerShell works just fine. However, since the batch files run in a different interpreter (running `.\your.bat` is basically the same as running `cmd /c .\your.bat`), changing the working directory via `cd %TMP%` in the (CMD) *child* process doesn't change the working directory for the (PowerShell) *parent* process.

The syntax you use for variables in batch files is always `%variable%`.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $PWD.Path
C:\
PS C:\> Get-Content .\test.bat
@echo off
echo before: %CD%
cd %TMP%
echo after:  %CD%
PS C:\> .\test.bat
before: C:\
after:  C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp
PS C:\> $PWD.Path
C:\
```

The batch file echoes the path of the current working directory (`%CD%`) before and after changing the working directory to `%TMP%`. The working directory of the parent process (PowerShell) remains unchanged (`$PWD.Path`).

Comment: That's a great answer but I guess I wasn't as clear as I could be with my question. Is there a way to get the value of an environment variable in a bat file that works regardless of cmd or powershell shell?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Perhaps it's my answer that wasn't clear enough. The syntax for (environment) variables in batch files is *always* `%variable%`, regardless of whether you run the batch file from PowerShell or CMD. Effectively batch files are always running in CMD, even when started from PowerShell.